# Adding a proxy section to a model in Sencha Touch 2 not MVC

Tags: extjs, model, proxy, touch, store

My goal here is to understand how models and stores are working and more specifically with 'localstorage'.

Here's the function I'm working on:

```
createModelAndStore: function() {
    console.log('Kitchensink.view.LocalStorage createModelAndStore starts');

    // Set up a model to use in our Store
    Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        config: {
            //proxy: {
            //    type: 'localstorage'
            //},
            fields: [
                {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
            ]
        }
    });

    var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        id: 'UserStore',
        model: 'User',
        data: [
            {
                'firstName': 'Tommy'
            }
        ]
    });
},
```

It's working perfectly like that. As soon as I remove the comments on the proxy section it fails miserably with 'Model with name "User" does not exist.'.
Can someone please explain to me what's happening?

I am not interested in moving the proxy definition in the store as I would like to use the '.save()' method on a model instance along with autosync.

Comment: Are dependencies loaded? I mean LocalStorage and its parent classes? What error messages say?

Comment: Console messages are:
Kitchensink.view.LocalStorage createModelAndStore starts
Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.data.Store#setModel] Model with name "User" does not exist.